# Outlook 2007 cannot copy paste (workaround/solution here)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, copy-paste

It seems this is quite a common problem that you cannot copypaste properly in Outlook 2007, and whenever I've checked for solutions, I haven't found any.

Common scenarios where you run into this issue:

- Copypasting from another program into Outlook message - nothing gets
  pasted into Outlook, but works when pasted into other programs
- Copying an email address from a person's properties within Outlook, and pasting it into another Outlook message (eg. doubleclicking a name, and copying the address from the dialog)

Comment: I ran into this problem with Outlook 2013 (couldn't paste into an email, but pasting into Word worked fine).  I resolved it by closing and restarting Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I have discovered the true culprit. It is to do with the Send to Bluetooth add-in (of all things!) in Outlook 2007. A similar discovery can be found in this thread: http://www.sevenforums.com/microsoft-office/304125-word-2007-copy-paste-issue.html

My previous answer also worked some of the time, but not 100 % of the time, until I disabled the Send to Bluetooth add-in. After that change, I have never had copy paste issues in Outlook 2007 in the past 10 months since my previous answer.

You can disable the add-in through:

1. Tools | Trust Center...
2. Add-ins...
3. Manage: COM Add-ins
4. Uncheck "Send to Bluetooth", and click "OK"
5. Check that it appears as Disabled

Now copypasting should work in all cases. From Outlook to other programs, from other programs to Outlook, and between Office programs.

Apparently the root cause is a bug in the Motorola bluetooth driver in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This has now worked for me for the past week at work, while I used to run into the issue almost daily.

1. In Outlook, open: Tools | Options | Mail Format | Editor Options |
   Advanced
2. Go to the heading: "Cut, copy, and paste"
3. Change the first four settings to "Keep Text Only"
4. And also untick the box for "Use
   smart cut and paste"

Unfortunately I'm not sure which of those two things is the main issue, but with these settings I haven't had any issues with copypasting anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try running Outlook as an Administrator and disable the add ons especially the "send to Bluetooth"

ran as normal user and i got mine to work.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't paste text into an email, and the other suggested solutions didn't work for me. I then tried Ctrl + V (rather than hitting "paste") and my text pasted straight in.